# waiting for user response in RStudio

Tags: r, rstudio

when i run RScripts, R never wait for user response.

```
AA <- readline("min mean?")  
BB <- readline("max min?")
CC <- readline("min var?")
DD <- readline("max var?")
```

the resualt

```
AA <- readline("min mean?")  
min mean? BB <- readline("max min?")
> CC <- readline("min var?")
min var? DD <- readline("max var?")
```

How can i make R to wait for use response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you click on `Run` button in the right top of current script window, your script will perform only one line. 
If you wanna to start your full script, you have to click on `Source` button beside with `Run`button.

But, actually, if you click on either of this buttons, you can get an input into the interactive mode below. So, write, please, your actions to start script.